# Unable to access Forms which are inside frames of HTML using VBA

Tags: html, vba

```
Set resultClasses = IeUsps.document.getElementsByTagName("FRAME") 
    For Each resultClass In resultClasses 
        MsgBox resultClass.Name 
    Set resultClasses1 = IeUsps.document.getElementsByTagName("form")           
         For Each resultClass1 In resultClasses1     
            MsgBox resultClass1.Name    
        Next resultClass1        
 Next resultClass
```

I have the above code, When I am running the above, I am able to see all the names of frames, but not forms inside of each frame.
I have to access, frame inside that required form, inside that some input tags. Please help.

Comment: Please Help.. I am going mad from week days..this is hamepring my work like anything..

Comment: Each frame has a different `Document` object: as you're looping through the frames you need to look for forms in each of those separate document objects...

Comment: Post some HTML source of how your frames and forms inside the frames is structured. And then let us know, what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim resultClasses, resultClass, resultClasses1, resultClass1

    Set resultClasses = IeUsps.document.getElementsByTagName("FRAME")
    For Each resultClass In resultClasses
        MsgBox resultClass.Name
        Set resultClasses1 = resultClass.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
        For Each resultClass1 In resultClasses1
            MsgBox resultClass1.Name
        Next resultClass1
    Next resultClass
End Sub
```

Comment: Same problem means what?  What *exactly* do you see when it runs?  Try changing the MsgBox calls to `Debug.Print` to capture the output. It would help if you could post the HTML source for the page you're working with: edit it down first to something representative if it's too large to post...

Comment: Dim resultClasses, resultClass, resultClasses1, resultClass1

    Set resultClasses = IeUsps.document.getElementsByTagName("FRAME")
    For Each resultClass In resultClasses
         Debug.Print resultClass.Name

        Set resultClasses1 = resultClass.document.getElementsByTagName("form")
        For Each resultClass1 In resultClasses1
            MsgBox resultClass1.Name
        Next resultClass1

    Next resultClass

Comment: debug.print is nt pritning anythimg.. Loop is not going inside the forms..resultClass1  is coming as empty always..

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant HTML source.

Comment: IeUsps.document.frames("RoomPane").document.forms("main").getElementsByTagName("input")("MEM").Value = "123456759".. I am able to access now, thanks for your responses

Comment: Thanks. This gave me some insight into a related issue I was having (seems I find a lot your your content on StackOverflow for VBA Tim!)

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem a while ago. If you want to access data from a frame after you press a button, you should wait for the page to load. After pressing the button, just add to your code the following:

```
    Dim Bongeszo As InternetExplorer
    Do
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 0.1, Now)
    Loop Until Bongeszo.document.readyState = "complete"
```

After I waited for the page to load, I could access all information inside frames. Let us know if it helped you.